# Call back after successful sharing of twitter and google plus

Tags: javascript, twitter, google-plus

how to implement callbacks aftersuccessful sharing of twitter and google plus . The following urls am using to share
Twitter: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=your url,
Google: https://plus.google.com/share?url=your url

Answer (score 0):

you better to open social links in a new tab using `target="_blank"`.You can not redirect from a social url

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening those URLs in popups/new tabs there isn't any method of getting successful sharing callbacks. The best you can do is use the JavaScript SDKs the services provide and listen for intent by the user that they are going to share.

Twitter has [events](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events) which can tell you when a user has clicked to tweet.

Google+ +1 button has [onstartinteraction](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/#tag_parameters) to tell you when the +1 widget has been opened.

Comment: I want call back after successful sharing abraham

Comment: As I said in my answer the services don't provide that.